# jQuery Fade - Breaking after second iteration thru

Tags: jquery

I have a small issue with a fade animation I'm assembling.
It's functioning correctly twice thru the animation, and includes one wrap that works correctly.

On the second wrap, it snaps to the first photo, not fade to.
I've looked a bit at delays, but with it working correctly the first time, I'm not so sure where to go from here.

Could someone please assist?
Thanks everyone.

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/REbuy/1/

Code Samples as Follows

jQuery:

```
var speed = 2000;
function switcher(){
$('.next').animate({opacity:1}, speed, 'linear', function()
    {
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $('.next+li').addClass('next');
        $(this).removeClass('next');
        $('.next').css('opacity',0);
        checker();
    });
}

function checker(){
        if($('.w-slides li:last').hasClass('current'))
        {
            $('.w-slides li:first').addClass('next');
        }
        else if($('.w-slides li:first').hasClass('next') && $('.w-slides li:last').hasClass('current'))
        {

            $('.w-slides li:first').addClass('current');        
            $('.w-slides li.current+li').addClass('next');
            $('.w-slides li:first').removeClass('next');
        }
    switcher();
    }
switcher();
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="w-fader">
        <ul class="w-slides">
            <li class="current"><img src="fader-img-1.png" /></li>
            <li class="next"><img src="fader-img-2.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="fader-img-3.png" /></li>      
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is when you wrap, you don't set the opacity of the first item back to zero.

I changed your `checker` function to this:

```
function checker(){
if($('.w-slides li:last').hasClass('current'))
    {
        $('.w-slides li:first').addClass('next').css('opacity',0);
    }
}
```

And it seems to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/REbuy/6/)

I guess alternatively, you could just move your call to `checker` to before the line in switcher where you set the opacity.

Comment: Thanks Matt. A simple mistake when I look at it, but firebug seems a bit quirky when updating all the values in real time.